Checking if Char is lowercase in Haskell
How would be a code in Haskell, where the program tells you, in Boolean, if the Char is lowercase or not.
isItLowercase (e: Char) : Bool
I need to use the most simple functions.

If you can't use library functions, and only need to handle letters a..z, you could use something like 'a' <= ... to compare Chars.

the OP doesn't seem to say they can't use library functions, in which case of course isLowerCase from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#g:1 is the way to go

Base (Data.Char) spells that isLower.

There is no need to use ord here, you can just use a range check with the character itself:
isLowerCase :: Char -> Bool
isLowerCase c = 'a' <= c && c <= 'z'
This will only work for ASCII characters, so abc…xyz.
That being said, please use the isLower :: Char -> Bool [Hackage] function: this will check the lowercase of any character, not only ASCII ones.

I think one correct answer would be:
import Data.Char


isLowercase :: Char -> Bool
isLowercase l | ord l >= 97 && ord l <= 122 = True
              | otherwise = False


The import is not needed. But if it is allowed, then isLowercase = isLower is significantly simpler and handles more cases correctly.
